# Javascript function cannot be executed twice

Tags: javascript

I'm kind of new to Javascript and I've bee wondering for hours how to solve my problem. I have a litle function associated to a button. It work once but I cannot get it to execute after the first time.

```
function CheckEmpty1(){return "false";}

function Generate(){    
    if(CheckEmpty1() == "true"){
        alert("Please fill all mandatory field.\n\nAll missing field are  black colored.\n\nPlease also make sure to make a choice for all radio button.");
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('TemplateOutput').style.display = "block";
        lol = "lol";
        document.getElementById('TemplateOutput').value = lol;
        lol = "test2";
    }
    return;
}
```

"TemplateOutput" is a simple textarea centered in the browser. The code is originally more complicated than that but while doing the test to ensure the problem was not coming from somewhere else, it reduced to that but still doesn't work.

The second "lol = "test2";" is just to check that if I make a change to the variable, it is suposed to apply the second time I hit the button.

it seems to be basic for me but I can't figure out why... any help?

thanks.

EDIT:

I think I found the source of my error in my original script. My original code look like this:

```
function Output(){
    Output = "CSD Troubleshooting: " + Troubleshoot + "\n";
    return Output;
}

function Generate(){
    FillVars();

    GenerateOutput = Output();
    alert(GenerateOutput);

}
function FillVars(){
    Troubleshoot = document.getElementById('Troubleshoot').value;
}
```

I reduced it to the minimum but it still behave the same way.

The problem is coming from the Output() function because it work fine if I do it like this:

```
GenerateOutput = document.getElementById('Troubleshoot').value;
alert(GenerateOutput);
```

or

```
GenerateOutput = Troubleshoot;
alert(GenerateOutput);
```

BEHAVIOR: I click the button. The alert is filling like it is suposed to be. The second time I click the button, it just do nothing.

regards,

Comment: U maybe have an error check your debug console.

Comment: Not related, but for the first occurrence of `lol`, make it `var lol` so as to not create a global variable on accident.

Comment: What do you expect the second time? If the display and value are already set, what would setting them again to the same values do ?

Comment: also `return false;` instead of string "false"

Comment: @Dalorzo: Given that the OP is comparing to the string `"true"`, that could be a style choice. (Not a style I'd recommend. :-) )

Comment: @karthik: what's invalid about it; the returned value will simply be `undefined`.

Comment: @karthik: That's perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: Try adding your html and Javascript here http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can double check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:

Your edit changes things markedly. The central issue is here:

```
function Output(){
    Output = "CSD Troubleshooting: " + Troubleshoot + "\n";
    return Output;
}
```

The first time you run that function, you *replace* the function with a string. The `Output` symbol is a reference to the function.

It looks like you might have a Visual Basic background. In JavaScript, you simply do this:

```
function Output(){
    return "CSD Troubleshooting: " + Troubleshoot + "\n";
}
```

or if you want it in a variable first, declare the variable (with `var`) and probably to avoid confusion use a different name:

```
function Output(){
    var result = "CSD Troubleshooting: " + Troubleshoot + "\n";
    return result;
}
```

---

**Original Answer**:

> The second "lol = "test2";" is just to check that if I make a change to the variable, it is suposed to apply the second time I hit the button.

It won't, because your previous

```
lol = "lol";
```

...line runs, setting it back to `"lol"`. You'll never see the code put `"test2"` into the input.

The line

```
document.getElementById('TemplateOutput').value = lol;
```

**copies** the value from `lol` to the `value` property. It does not make the value property a reference to the variable `lol`. Changing the variable later has no effect, because there is no continuing link between it and the `value` property.

Since the `if` block in your code will never run, let's just look at the `else` block. Here, in detail, is what happens:

```
// 1
document.getElementById('TemplateOutput').style.display = "block";
```

That looks in the DOM for the element with the `id` "TemplateOutput", and sets its `style` object's `display` property to `"block"`.

```
// 2
lol = "lol";
```

That assigns the value `"lol"` to the `lol` variable. Unless you've declared `lol` somewhere you haven't shown, it also creates an *implicit global variable*. Details: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

```
// 3
document.getElementById('TemplateOutput').value = lol;
```

That **copies** the value `"lol"` from the `lol` variable into the `value` property of the input.

```
// 4
lol = "test2";
```

That copies the value `"test2"` into the `lol` variable.

Comment: Yeah, My logic was wrong in my test. I guess I tried too many thing and I did something like that. I edited my post above. Could you have a look at it to check where I'm wrong in my original script?

Comment: @DrizztDoUrden: You're replacing the function with a string. I've updated the answer.

Comment: that's it!? I have a VB and C++ background, you're right. I'm starting with JS. A BIG thanks to you, you save my life today! :D